# SQL to update a table only if that table exists in the database

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a mySQL database that might have a table named `jason`.
A separate instance of the database may not have the `jason` table (it would have other tables in common)

I'd like to run a simple update against both databases but the update is for the `jason` table.

I know I can do something like

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `jason`;
```

Is it possible to run an Update something like:

```
IF EXISTS `jason` UPDATE `jason` SET...
```

I can't seem to get anything to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run the update statement, if the table didn't exist, it will fail and cause no damage.

Comment: great answer (15 char padding)

Comment: If I run this in phpMyAdmin, or another DB client as a part of a larger set of updates it fails and stops the query.  Is there a way to tell mySQL to ignore these types of errors?

Comment: Sorry, I'm down voting, that seems unclean. That's how I have my app right now, and it's filling my error log with entries.  Yes, they don't "hurt" anything, but I consider my error log a list of TODOs to fix, so I don't like anything in my error logs

Comment: It causes no damage if you're ready to catch the error it creates, otherwise it can spill to an event log, interrupt some other process or cause a failure down the road. That's the exact reason why we have `CREATE TABLEIF NOT EXISTS`.

Answer (score 0):

If you name a non-existant table, the update statement will fail to compile.  You'll need to generate dynamic SQL and execute it only when the table exists.

Answer (score 0):

You could also refer to these [mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tables-table.html). All the schema information is in a database, so essentially you can do any queries in the same fashion. Examples towards the bottom.

Answer (score -2):

It won't fail but if you insist, you can do a work around:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table1)
   UPDATE Table1 SET (...) WHERE Column1='SomeValue'
ELSE
   INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (...)
```

Comment: You can't actually use that syntax in arbitrary scripts in mysql, so it won't work.